# Delete a product from inventory in Odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How do you delete a product,for example 'green cup' in inventory 'INV' from Odoo 9 . I am using Postgresql 9.3 as the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me you are talking about an inventory adjustment. If that is the case, if the inventory adjustment has not yet been validated, just edit it and you should see a trashcan to the right of the product line. Once the inventory adjustment has been validated you cannot remove a product from it and there wouldn't be any point, because the relevant stock moves have already been created to set the inventory to the amount specified. If this was done in error and you need to set the inventory to the previous value, just create a new inventory adjustment with the product in question and set the real quantity to the previous value.